# How to correctly extrapolate function?

Tags: list-manipulation, calculus-and-analysis, numerics, interpolation

There is a function: `` f={{10, 0.500074`}, {11, 0.502676`}, {12, 0.510451`}, {13,  0.507502`}, {14, 0.52768`}, {15, 0.625164`}, {16, 0.935248`}, {17,  1.826161`}, {18, 3.845598`}, {19, 8.293859`}, {20, 18.014295`}, {21, 39.20736`}, {22, 85.3836`}, {23, 185.975252`}, {24,  405.095196`}, {25, 882.399269`}, {26, 1922.095421`}, {27,  4186.829292`}, {28, 9120.018288`}} ``

How to correctly extrapolate this function in Mathematica? I would like to get `f[9], f[8], f[7], f[6], f[5]...` and `f[29], f[30], f[31]...`

I am interested in the function values for positive arguments only.

Comment: Hint: `ListPlot[Map[{#[[1]],Log[#[[2]]]}&,...yourdata...]]`

Answer (score 4):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

data = {{10, 0.500074`}, {11, 0.502676`}, {12, 0.510451`}, {13, 
    0.507502`}, {14, 0.52768`}, {15, 0.625164`}, {16, 0.935248`}, {17, 
    1.826161`}, {18, 3.845598`}, {19, 8.293859`}, {20, 18.014295`}, {21, 
    39.20736`}, {22, 85.3836`}, {23, 185.975252`}, {24, 405.095196`}, {25, 
    882.399269`}, {26, 1922.095421`}, {27, 4186.829292`}, {28, 9120.018288`}};

ListLogPlot[data]
```

[image]

Based on this plot, model the log of the data with a piecewise linear function with a break at `x0`

```
model = Piecewise[{{a*x + b, 0 < x <= x0}, {c*x + d, x > x0}}]
```

[image]

Fitting the model to the data

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[{#[[1]], Log[#[[2]]]} & /@ data,
   {model, 14 < x0 < 16, c > 0, b + a*x0 == d + c*x0},
   {a, b, c, d, x0}, x] // Normal
```

[image]

The function is then

```
f[x_] = E^nlm // PiecewiseExpand
```

[image]

```
Show[
 LogPlot[f[x], {x, 1, 35}],
 ListLogPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image]

The mean square error is

```
mse = Total[((f /@ Range[10, 28]) - data[[All, 2]])^2]/Length[data]

(* 2753.02 *)
```

Answer (score 0):

Put in your model with parameters this way:

```
g = NonlinearModelFit[f, {a + b Exp[c x]}, {a, b, c}, x];

Plot[g[x], {x, 0, 30},
 Epilog -> {Red, Point /@ f}]
```

[image]

```
g[9]
```

Comment: Sorry, but it's very strange solution, g[9] cannot be -1697.39

Comment: Why did you choose this expression ```a + b x + c x^2 + d x^3``` for fitting?

Comment: Thanks! It is better, but for instance g[11]≠f[11] (0.225843≠0.502676)

Comment: It is a *statistical* model... it need not give every point exactly.  If you need that, then add terms and parameters to your model.